# Why is the control inaccessible due to its protection level?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm trying to access a control's text property from program.cs and it says that it is inaccessible due to protected level. How can I fix this please?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: FWIW, a question like this means you are going down a path of very tight coupling (accessing myForm.myControl.Text outside of myForm's code is a bad idea).

Comment: is this a bad idea only because it can be insecure? or are there other reasons too?

Comment: It's a bad idea because it exposes implementation details more than it needs to. What if you, in the future, decide to replace the text box with a drop-down list of choices?

Comment: hmmm point taken. thanks for clearing that up arikkallen :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is the default property for controls and can be solved by:

1. Going into Design-View for the Form that contains the specified Control
2. Then changing the Control's Modifiers property to Public or Internal.

[image: Control Properties > Modifiers Screenshot]

Comment: Note: just to emphasize as this seems to have been very unclear by the asker, this is the *control's instance itself* that's protected (i.e., the variable holding the control), not the *`.Text` property*, which is public.

Comment: It is worth pointing out for SEO that this works in xamarin XAML as well

Comment: Tried this for textbox and got the error "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'textbox'

Answer (score 6):

**Control Protection level Resolved**

Go to designer file search control By ID e.g txtModel change **protected** modifier to **public** modifier

Comment: This is not a good idea. Better is to access value of control thru property of class, where control is used.

Comment: @asad It is not a good idea to access the child controls directly because you cannot change/maintain/modify the child without updating the grandparent. This is encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `x:FieldModifier="public"`
e.g.

```
<TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="AccessibleTextBlock" />
```

as explained here: [Modifying XAML named field visibility](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/06/modifying-xaml-field-visibility/)

In my case, I put UserControl in another DLL. WPF’s convention is to set all named fields as `internal` by default. Using the `x:FieldModifier="public"` has solved the issue.

Comment: Question was tagged WinForms.  No XAML.

Comment: Anyway answer helps me for WPF, thanks to Google results

Answer (score 1):

The concept behind is the protection level. As we have studied in Object Oriented Paradigm keep your class members variables private and set or get it from Property.Thats why it is not a good approach